# Проектирование реляционной БД при многомерной структуре данных

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Изучаю Ruby on Rails. В целях самообразования с другом решили написать приложение для вывода расписания движения общественного транспорта (я пишу backend, он -- клиент на Android).

Собственно, имеется такая структура данных:
[image: Структура]
Остановка может входить в несколько маршрутов.

Вопрос: как грамотно спроектировать базу данных? Сложность состоит в том, что у каждой остановки есть определенный набор времен, в зависимости от маршрута, в который данная остановка входит. Получается какая-то многомерная структура. Наборы могут отличаться по размеру друг от друга, опять же, в зависимости от маршрута (например, для маршр_1 их 4, а для маршр_2 -- 6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю, что:

- маршруты могут иметь разные планы, например: прямой и обратный
- остановки могут фигурировать в разных маршрутах

**таблица routs_items: маршруты**

- id: id записи
- number: номер маршрута
- name: название маршрута

**таблица routs_bus_stops: остановки маршрутов**

- id: id записи
- name: название остановки

**таблица routs_plans: планы маршрутов**

- id: id записи
- rout_id: id запись маршрута
- bus_stop_id: id запись остановки
- time: время прибытия

Выборка данных для Вашей таблицы (той, что на картинке) будет из **routes_plans** с **LEFT JOIN** данных из **routs_items** и **routes_bus_stops**, с сортировкой по **route_items.name** и **routs_plans.time**. Группировка времени прибытия для каждой остановки по конкретному маршруту выполняется через back-end.

Архитектуру БД рекомендую делать максимально простой и лаконичной. Лучше две таблицы, чем одна большая.